# How to combine to git repos coming from the same svn original project

Tags: git, svn, combine

I have two different git repositories that started as a clone of the same svn project. Naturally they share a good part of history. They also have different changes.

How can I "merge" them properly? What git concept is appropriate for this kind of merge?

Considering a `readme.txt` file that existed in svn, it should be seen that was forked and changed in two branches (the two masters of the git projects) after which was merged. Is this even possible?

---

**Clarifications:**

In my case I found that namek-0.6 is identical with the namek-0.6-second. The tree on the left contains a full svn history while the one on the right it started with a first commit from some snapshot of the svn. What I would like is that all the changed files in the namek-0.6 and after will continue the history over the stuff from the left.

[image: two different git repos]

Comment: If you converted to Git two times you now have two *unrelated* repositories as far as Git is concerned. They just happen to have similar contents. You can of course merge this but it'll be two-way merge.

Comment: Yes I have two unrelated repositories. So you suggest that I should use a  merge with --allow-unrelated-histories? Isn't better to cherry pick, rebase, or other kind of operations? I was thinking that maybe is enough to just tell to git that two specific commits make the branches identical and make git check the equivalence.

Comment: Every “normal” Git operation is based on the fact that a common ancestor exists. Whatever you do will always fall back to a two-way merge. IIRC you can use some dark magic to associate two otherwise unrelated commits, but I left that knowledge at my previous employer.